# Old python (<=3.8.9) not compatible with new Mac (macOS Ventura 13.4.1)

Tags: python, macos, conda, pyenv

I cannot install versions of python 3 that are between 3.8.1 and 3.8.9 (including) in my new Mac.

I tried with pyenv and also with conda.

---

## Pyenv

```
% pyenv install 3.8.1

python-build: use openssl from homebrew
python-build: use readline from homebrew
Downloading Python-3.8.1.tar.xz...
\-\> https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.8.1/Python-3.8.1.tar.xz
Installing Python-3.8.1...
python-build: use readline from homebrew
python-build: use zlib from xcode sdk

BUILD FAILED (OS X 13.4.1 using python-build 20180424)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /var/folders/p3/4d4l80y16r36dq3s5gf8kq4w0000gn/T/python-build.20230816162703.3291
Results logged to /var/folders/p3/4d4l80y16r36dq3s5gf8kq4w0000gn/T/python-build.20230816162703.3291.log

Last 10 log lines:
checking for --with-cxx-main=\<compiler\>... no
checking for clang++... no
configure:

By default, distutils will build C++ extension modules with "clang++".
If this is not intended, then set CXX on the configure command line.

checking for the platform triplet based on compiler characteristics... darwin
configure: error: internal configure error for the platform triplet, please file a bug report
make: \*\*\* No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
```

## Conda

```
% conda install python==3.8.1

Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): / DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (1): repo.anaconda.com:443
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (1): repo.anaconda.com:443
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (1): repo.anaconda.com:443
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (1): repo.anaconda.com:443

- DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https://repo.anaconda.com:443 "GET /pkgs/main/noarch/current_repodata.json HTTP/1.1" 304 0
  \\ DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https://repo.anaconda.com:443 "GET /pkgs/main/osx-arm64/current_repodata.json HTTP/1.1" 304 0
  DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https://repo.anaconda.com:443 "GET /pkgs/r/noarch/current_repodata.json HTTP/1.1" 304 0
  DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https://repo.anaconda.com:443 "GET /pkgs/r/osx-arm64/current_repodata.json HTTP/1.1" 304 0
  done
  Solving environment: unsuccessful initial attempt using frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
  Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): \\ DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (1): repo.anaconda.com:443
  DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (1): repo.anaconda.com:443
  DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (1): repo.anaconda.com:443
  DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (1): repo.anaconda.com:443
- DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https://repo.anaconda.com:443 "GET /pkgs/r/noarch/repodata.json HTTP/1.1" 304 0
  DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https://repo.anaconda.com:443 "GET /pkgs/main/noarch/repodata.json HTTP/1.1" 304 0
  DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https://repo.anaconda.com:443 "GET /pkgs/r/osx-arm64/repodata.json HTTP/1.1" 304 0
  \\ DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https://repo.anaconda.com:443 "GET /pkgs/main/osx-arm64/repodata.json HTTP/1.1" 304 0
  done
  Solving environment: unsuccessful initial attempt using frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

- python==3.8.1

Current channels:

- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/osx-arm64
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/osx-arm64
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
- https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/osx-arm64
- https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page.
```

---

I think the problem is related to the new Apple Clang versions > 13.0.0 being incompatible with older python versions. See here https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/issues/2112 .

---

Comment: No, that's definitely not what the first error says.  What that says is that it doesn't know how to configure itself for the combination of MacOS and AMD64, because such a combination did not exist in 2018 when that build happened.  You should be able to install an x64 version (which will work).

Comment: Effectively same issue as duplicate and identical solution. As Tim points out, Conda Forge never built Python v3.8.1 for **osx-arm64**. If you really need it, you can emulate. Please let me know if you'd like the issue left open re: the `pyenv` approach (but maybe we should drop the Conda part of the question - bordering on multiple questions).